# Why is accessing one element in a numpy array slowing my program down so much?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm writing a simulation (2D Ising model simulation). It requires picking a random element in a 2D array, and multiplying the value by -1. Elements in the 2D array are spin sites, and the value is either +1 or -1.

I forgot to add a line of code which actually changes the spin site. Adding this (one!) line of code significantly slows the program down. All spin sites are defaulted to -1.

I've tried editing other functions which do some basic math (calculating total energy of spin sites, basically just multiplication and addition) to sneak that -1 flip in, by changing some additions to subtractions to account for that -1 flip, thereby avoiding having to access that array element. Still slows it down insanely.

Here's the result of the time command, without flipping the random array element.

real    0m1.425s
user    0m1.685s
sys     0m1.078s

And the result, from adding one line of code (shown below)
real    0m26.615s
user    0m27.019s
sys     0m0.920s

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# As seen in lecture:
# Ising model implementation with Metropolis algorithm
# Based on IsingViz.py from Landau, et al.

N     = (2000, 2000) # number of spin sites                                   
num_steps = 20*N[0]*N[1]  # number of iterations
B     = 0.05         # magnetic field                               
mu    = .33          # g mu (not needed if B=0)
J     = 1.           # exchange energy                              
k     = 1.
t     = 1.
np.random.seed() 
state0 = -1*np.ones(N) # Start with an arbitrary spin configuration
Evals = []
def energy(State, J, mu, B):
    # Energy will call row_energy on every row in State, and on 
    # every row of its transpose.
    total_energy = 0
    for row in State:
        total_energy += row_energy(row, J, mu, B)
    for col in State.transpose():
        total_energy += row_energy(col, J, mu, B)
    return total_energy
def row_energy(S, J, mu, B):
    first_set = np.concatenate([np.array([S[-1]]), S[:-1]])
    FirstTerm = np.sum(-J*first_set[:-1]*first_set[1:])
    SecondTerm = np.sum(-mu*S*B)
    return (FirstTerm + SecondTerm)

def energy_change(S, coor):
    """Determine the change in energy if spin `i` is flipped

    `(i+1) % len(S)` implements the periodic boundary condition.
    """
    x = coor[0]
    y = coor[1]
    # Multiply spin site by all adjacent elements
    S_left  = S[x-1,y]
    S_right = S[(x+1) % len(S),y]
    S_up    = S[x,(y+1) % len(S)]
    S_down  = S[x,y-1]
    return 2*J*S[x,y]*(S_left + S_right + S_up + S_down % len(S)) + 2*B*mu*S[x,y]

def TwoDIsing(state0, num_steps, J, mu, B, kT):
    ES = energy(state0, J, mu, B)
    energy_values = []
    energy_values.append(ES)
    # Contains a copy of the state configuration so we don't have to store
    # 2**N**2 * # of time step elements
    state_configs = np.array([state0, state0])
    deltas = [] # A lighter way of keeping track of how the state changes.
    rands = np.random.randint(2000, size=(num_steps,2))
    count = 1
    for x, y in rands:
        #test_state = state_configs[-1]
        # Trial step: flip spin at one random site
        #test_state[x,y] *= -1.
        state_configs[1][x][y] *= -1
        ET = ES + energy_change(state_configs[-1], (x,y))
        if np.exp((ES-ET)/(kT)) > np.random.random():
            #state_configs[-1] = test_state      # replace the state, or
            ES = ET
            deltas.append((x,y))
        else:
            # advance the previous state forward
            state_configs[-1]=state_configs[-2]
            deltas.append(())
        energy_values.append(ES)
        count += 1
        if count % 1000 == 0: print((count / num_steps)*100," %.....................")
    return state_configs, energy_values, deltas
```

Comment: What is `energy`? What kind of object is `ES` after `ES = energy(state0, J, mu, B)`?

Comment: Also, what kind of object is `state0`?

Comment: what does energy_change? generally, you sould not acces numpy arrays by one, use some array function like prefixsumm,  mapping. etc. Numpy copies arrays from python to native code and then back. Generelly you should not use obejct  abstractions with numpy. Minor: having state_configs as numpy array is useless

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever update `state_configs[0]`. Also, it doesn't sound like array element access is actually causing the slowdown. It sounds like the slowdown is from taking a different code path, such as a different branch of the if/else. We can't tell for sure from what you've posted, since you haven't posted something runnable.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. I will try and answer all confusions here. @user2357112 Energy is scalar value, calculated from a 2D array of values either +1 or -1. Its function is above. state0 is the initial state of the system, initialized to a 2000x2000 array of -1.

Comment: @user8426627 energy_change calculates what the energy is for a specific coordinate in the state. The total energy is the sum of energy of adjacent sites. So changing a spin site, and calculating the energy there, gives the change in energy of the entire site. Good note on having state_configs operate like that, I will tweak it. I looked into maps, but since the next state sort of depends on the success or failure of the previous state, would it still work? I'm not very familiar with those functions

Comment: @user2357112 Wow you were right, using state_configs as a 2d array was wasteful, and insanely inefficient. It was quicker just to multiply by -1 again to undo the change than it was access a previously stored copy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Error was in using state_configs to store two copies of the state. Much quicker to not do that. Read comments for details

```py
def TwoDIsing(state0, num_steps, J, mu, B, kT):
    ES = energy(state0, J, mu, B)
    energy_values = []
    energy_values.append(ES)
    # Contains a copy of the state configuration so we don't have to store
    # 2**N**2 * # of time step elements
    #state_configs = np.array([state0, state0])
    deltas = [] # A lighter way of keeping track of how the state changes.
    rands = np.random.randint(2000, size=(num_steps,2))
    count = 1
    for x, y in rands:
        #test_state = state_configs[-1]
        # Trial step: flip spin at one random site
        #test_state[x,y] *= -1.
        state0[x][y] *= -1
        ET = ES + energy_change(state0, (x,y))
        if np.exp((ES-ET)/(kT)) > np.random.random():
            #state_configs[-1] = test_state      # replace the state, or
            ES = ET
            deltas.append((x,y))
        else:
            # advance the previous state forward
            state0[x,y] *= -1
            deltas.append(())
        energy_values.append(ES)
        count += 1
        if count % 1000 == 0: print((count / num_steps)*100," %.....................")
    return state_configs, energy_values, deltas
```